# BufferedReader ( scanner )

Tags: java

This is what i have for now. I want to know, how many times i have some word in .txt document . Now i am trying to use `BufferedReader` didn't manage well enough. I guess here is a easier way to solve this, but i don't know.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class TekstiAnalüsaator {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InputStream baidid = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
        InputStreamReader tekst = new InputStreamReader(baidid, "UTF-8");
        BufferedReader puhverdab = new BufferedReader(tekst);
        String rida = puhverdab.readLine();
        while (rida != null){
            System.out.println("Reading: " + rida);
            rida = puhverdab.readLine();
        }
        puhverdab.close();
    }
}
```

I want to search words using this structure. What file, then what word i need to find, (return) how many times, this word is in the file.

```
TekstiAnalüsaator analüsaator = new TekstiAnalüsaator("kiri.txt");
int esinemisteArv = analüsaator.sõneEsinemisteArv("kala");
```

Comment: What is wrong with your approach?  Reading one line of the file at a time and checking seems reasonable to me.  This assumes that words cannot be broken over multiple lines.

Comment: You can use java8 way to use stream for reading, but I prefer this "older" way, because it seems for me more readable and intuitive. For stream check eg [mkyong page](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-stream-read-a-file-line-by-line/)

Comment: btw2 if it works and you are just asking for improvement, then you can use [codereview portal](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I think what is wrong is counting the occurance of the word in the line

Answer (score 0):

Please see the code example below. This should solve the issue you are facing.

```
import java.io.*;

public class CountWords {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(count("Test.java", "static"));
    }

    public static int count(String filename, String wordToSearch) throws IOException {
        int tokencount = 0;
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String s;
        int linecount = 0;

        String line;

        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (s.contains(wordToSearch))
                tokencount++;
            // System.out.println(s);

        }
        return tokencount;
    }

}
```

Comment: What about lines with contains the word several times?

Comment: we need to split s into subset of words and increment count for each occurrence of word.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit of a tricky question because counting **words** in a string is not so simple task. Your approach is fine for reading the file line by line so now the problem is how to count the word matches.

For example you can do the simple check for matches like that:

```
    public static int getCountOFWordsInLine(String line, String test){
        int count=0;
        int index=0;
        while(line.indexOf(test,index ) != -1) {
            count++;
            index=line.indexOf(test,index)+1;

        }

        return count;
        }
```

The problem with that approach is that if your word is "test" and your string is "Next word matches asdfa**test**sdf"  it will count it as a match. So you can try using some more advanced regex:

```
public static int getCountOFWordsInLine(String line, String word) {
    int count = 0;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b"+word+"\\b");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    while (matcher.find())
        count++;
    return count;
}
```

It actually checks for the word surrounded by **\b** which is word break

It still won't find the word if it start with uppercase though. If you want to make it case insensitive you can modify the previous method by changing everything to lowercase prior to searching. But it depends on your definition of word.

The whole program will become:

public class MainClass {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    try {
            InputStream baidid = new FileInputStream("c:\\test.txt");
            InputStreamReader tekst = new InputStreamReader(baidid, "UTF-8");
            BufferedReader puhverdab = new BufferedReader(tekst);
            String rida = puhverdab.readLine();
            String word="test";
            int count=0;
            while (rida != null){
                System.out.println("Reading: " + rida);
                count+=getCountOFWordsInLine(rida,word );
                rida = puhverdab.readLine();

            }               
            System.out.println("count:"+count);
            puhverdab.close();

    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static int getCountOFWordsInLine(String line, String test) {
    int count = 0;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b"+test+"\\b");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    while (matcher.find())
        count++;
    return count;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.until.regex.*;

public class TA
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        InputStream baidid = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
        InputStreamReader tekst = new InputStreamReader(baidid, "UTF-8");
        BufferedReader puhverdab = new BufferedReader(tekst);

        String rida;
        String word = argv[0];  // search word passed via command line
        int count1=0, count2=0, count3=0, count4=0;
        Pattern P1 = Pattern.compile("\\b" + word + "\\b");
        Pattern P2 = Pattern.compile("\\b" + word + "\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        while ((rida = puhverdab.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Reading: " + rida);

            // Version 1 : counts lines containing [word]
            if (rida.contains(word)) count1++;

            // Version 2: counts every instance of [word]
            into pos=0;
            while ((pos = rida.indexOf(word, pos)) != -1) { count2++; pos++; }

            // Version 3: looks for surrounding whitespace
            Matcher m = P1.matcher(rida);
            while (m.find()) count3++; 

            // Version 4: looks for surrounding whitespace (case insensitive)
            Matcher m = P2.matcher(rida);
            while (m.find()) count4++;
        }
        System.out.println("Found exactly " + count1 + " line(s) containing word: \"" + word + "\"");
        System.out.println("Found word \"" + word + "\" exactly " + count2 + " time(s)");
        System.out.println("Found word \"" + word + "\" surrounded by whitespace " + count3 + " time(s).");
        System.out.println("Found, case insensitive search, word \"" + word + "\" surrounded by whitespace " + count4 + " time(s).");
        puhverdab.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: And what about if the word occurs two times in the string ride? You will count it only once

Comment: I have added 4 versions regarding "What does this question actually ask?"  I could probably think of 2 or 3 more!  Text/Processing String/Processing is what I focus, and there are dozens of versions of "an answer" in NLP - all the time.

Comment: if (rida.toLowerCase().contains(wordLowCase)) count5++;  // Version 5 : counts lines containing [word] (Case-Insensitive)

Answer (score -1):

This reads line-by-line as you've already done, splits a line by whitespace to obtain individual words, and checks each word for a match.

```
int countWords(String filename, String word) throws Exception {
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    int count = 0;
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
        for (String w : words)
            if (w.equals(word))
                count++;
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
    reader.close();
    return count;
}
```

Comment: If you don't already know whether it works or not, this is a question, not an answer.

Comment: @EJP I'm sorry for asking the OP if this meets their needs. Of course I have tested and can confirm that this works for what I perceive to be the OP's intent. This is a pretty trivial complaint for a downvote...

Comment: So you didn't need to ask at all. The OP is looking for answers, not questions. You don't have any evidence about downvotes. They are a secret ballot. Don't speculate.

Comment: Dang, this site really is a tough nut to crack. I was just trying to be friendly.